# Has pandas.read_csv date parsing options changed? How can we use parse_dates with string list of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

How can we read a file with several date columns that need to be specified as strings. Using *integers* works.

```
pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[1]) # works
pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[colname]) # fails
```

Error is:

```
ValueError: Missing column provided to 'parse_dates': ...
```

Comment: Are you sure the value of `colname` is actually present...? No leading/trailing spaces etc...? eg: What does `df = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=0)` and then `df.columns[1]` show you?

Comment: Which version are you using? working in `'0.25.3'`

Comment: dev version off master, or very near to it.